# How to pull text from HTML comment tag with Google Apps Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script

With Google Apps Script, I like to pull ticker names in array, only the first text section before the first vertical bar in each line(for example, only "TROW" out of "TROW|222.38|27987" in the first line) in the following HTML comment tag.

```
<! –– TS
TROW|222.38|27987
CATH|56.22|1170
DIT|161.30|138
VTI|232.95|293098
SIOX|2.25|132517
FFA|21.29|2798
IVV|452.90|280931
PSMB|17.17|2992
URTH|131.96|5770
VOO|414.60|439729
IOO|74.25|17178
SPXL|123.55|471362
UPRO|131.48|457776
CIXX|19.39|546
VO|247.64|32306
TRGP|44.66|46449
VT|106.30|125245
AZZ|54.05|2210
NBTX|12.79|1
SHE|105.81|928
TE ––>
```

Comment: Is there a specific step where you are getting stuck? Can you show us the related code?

Comment: I tried this with a little simplified example.  From here, I couldn't figure out how to get only ticker name.
function test() {
  var comment =
    "TROW|223.47|202429 CATH|56.53|5149 DIT|161.27|834 FEX|89.99|6572 VTI|233.84|2018614";
  var tickers = comment.trim().split('\n').map(s => s.split(' '));
  console.log(tickers);
}

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add the new information there, instead of in a comment. The new information is directly relevant to the question. Also, reading code in a comment is not easy. If you add the code to the question, you can format the code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it makes little sense for this particular case. So rather for educational purposes:

```js
var txt = `<! –– TS
TROW|222.38|27987
CATH|56.22|1170
DIT|161.30|138
VTI|232.95|293098
SIOX|2.25|132517
FFA|21.29|2798
IVV|452.90|280931
PSMB|17.17|2992
URTH|131.96|5770
VOO|414.60|439729
IOO|74.25|17178
SPXL|123.55|471362
UPRO|131.48|457776
CIXX|19.39|546
VO|247.64|32306
TRGP|44.66|46449
VT|106.30|125245
AZZ|54.05|2210
NBTX|12.79|1
SHE|105.81|928
TE ––>`

var words = txt.split('\n').map(x => x.split('|')[0]).slice(1,-1);

console.log(words);
```

**Update**

```js
var txt = `<! –– TS
TROW|Strong|222.38|27987
CATH|Strong|56.22|1170
TE ––>`

var words = txt.split('\n').map(x => [x.split('|')[0],x.split('|')[1]]).slice(1,-1);

console.log(words); output: [ ['TROW', 'Strong'], ['CATH', 'Strong'] ]
```

Comment: One more help please!  How can I add another column and add another text to get like this?  ['TROW', 'Strong'] ['CATH', 'Strong'] .....   Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure if I understand how your new data looks like. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry my last comment was not clear to you.  What I mean is the original var txt doesn't include |Strong.  So the variable text is like var txt = `<! –– TS
TROW|222.38|27987
CATH|56.22|1170
TE ––>`   After pulling ticker name only from the variable, later I want to add 'Strong' to the each ticker name and  get the final output [ ['TROW', 'Strong'], ['CATH', 'Strong'] ].  Thank again for your help!

Comment: Do you meant this: `var words_strong = words.map(x => [x, 'strong'])` ?

Comment: Perfect!  Now I understood what map does.  Thank you again very much!